# (Arduino Uno reflashed as USB HID) How to send Scroll Lock key?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, hid

I am having a hard time properly using USB HID buffers, and want to send the scroll lock key when I press the button.

I have tried sending what I thought was scroll lock (0x47) and it sends the ctrl, left alt, and right alt keys instead. 
I used the table here for reference: https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hut1_12v2.pdf

This is loosely based off of http://mitchtech.net/arduino-usb-hid-keyboard/

```
/* Arduino USB Keyboard HID demo
 * Cut/Copy/Paste Keys
 */

#define SCRLCK  0x47
//#define KEY_LEFT_SHIFT  0x02
//#define KEY_RIGHT_CTRL  0x10
//#define KEY_RIGHT_SHIFT 0x20

uint8_t buf[8] = { 
  0 };  /* Keyboard report buffer */

#define PIN_PTT 2
//#define PIN_CUT 6
//#define PIN_PASTE 7

int state = 1;
int prevState;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(PIN_PTT, INPUT);
  //pinMode(PIN_CUT, INPUT);
  //pinMode(PIN_PASTE, INPUT);
  // Enable internal pull-ups
  digitalWrite(PIN_PTT, 1); 
  //digitalWrite(PIN_CUT, 1);
  //digitalWrite(PIN_PASTE, 1); 

  delay(200);
}

void loop() 
{
  state = digitalRead(PIN_PTT);
  if (prevState != state) {
    buf[0] = SCRLCK;   // Scroll Lock
    // buf[2] = 27;    // Letter X
    // buf[2] = 123;    // Cut key: Less portable
    Serial.write(buf, 8); // Send keypress
    prevState = state;
    releaseKey();
  } 
}

void releaseKey() 
{
  buf[0] = 0;
  Serial.write(buf, 8); // Release key  
  delay(100);
}
```

I expect scroll lock to be sent, but upon using passmark KeyboardTest I see that ctrl, left alt, and right alt are sent instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should send the first key code starting at offset 2:

buf[2] = SCRLCK;

Offset 0 is used for key modifier flags like ctrl, alt, etc.